# Are there other blocks that don't return all the components like the battery

Tags: space-engineers

If you deconstruct a battery you don't get back your power cells.

Are there any other blocks that you should not just deconstruct to move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the battery has this mechanic, it's designed to prevent abuse of the starting charge by grinding and welding batteries over and over by the player.

All other blocks (excluding blocks from mods) are save to deconstruct as often as you like.